# Setting-up Beetel BG64 3G USB modem in ubuntu 13.10 [How-To]

Tags: installation, internet, usb-modem

I have just bought a Beetel BG64 usb modem.
This modem is working fine on Win 7 but not in ubuntu 13.10 (saucy).

I have tried a lot, but still not working.I have posted the output of `lsusb` & `usb-devices` necessarily. Any suggestion will be helpful. Thank you in advance.

## edit:

#### What I did:

- without attaching the dongle I pressed <kbd>Ctrl</kbd>+<kbd>Meta</kbd>+<kbd>T</kbd>, then typed:

```
mount /dev/sr
```

And pressed Tab. This gave me the only suggestion,

```
mount /dev/sr0
```

- Again I attached the dongle , then did the same, and the output is:

```
mount /dev/sr
sr0  sr1
```

- Now I pulled out the dongle from my machine and did:

```
lsusb
```

And I got the result:

```
Bus 001 Device 001: ID 1d6b:0002 Linux Foundation 2.0 root hub<br>
Bus 002 Device 003: ID 0d8c:0201 C-Media Electronics, Inc. CM6501<br>
Bus 002 Device 002: ID 04f3:0212 Elan Microelectronics Corp. Laser Mouse<br>
Bus 002 Device 001: ID 1d6b:0001 Linux Foundation 1.1 root hub<br>
```

- Then I connected it to the machine again and did the same, and got:

```
lsusb
```

```
Bus 001 Device 004: ID 2020:0002  <br>
Bus 001 Device 001: ID 1d6b:0002 Linux Foundation 2.0 root hub<br>
Bus 002 Device 003: ID 0d8c:0201 C-Media Electronics, Inc. CM6501<br>
Bus 002 Device 002: ID 04f3:0212 Elan Microelectronics Corp. Laser Mouse<br>
Bus 002 Device 001: ID 1d6b:0001 Linux Foundation 1.1 root hub<br>
<br>
```

- without connecting the dongle I did:

```
usb-devices
```

and got:

```
T:  Bus=01 Lev=00 Prnt=00 Port=00 Cnt=00 Dev#=  1 Spd=480 MxCh= 9<br>
D:  Ver= 2.00 Cls=09(hub  ) Sub=00 Prot=00 MxPS=64 #Cfgs=  1<br>
P:  Vendor=1d6b ProdID=0002 Rev=03.11<br>
S:  Manufacturer=Linux 3.11.0-15-generic ehci_hcd<br>
S:  Product=EHCI Host Controller<br>
S:  SerialNumber=0000:00:02.1<br>
C:  #Ifs= 1 Cfg#= 1 Atr=e0 MxPwr=0mA<br>
I:  If#= 0 Alt= 0 #EPs= 1 Cls=09(hub  ) Sub=00 Prot=00 Driver=hub<br>

T:  Bus=02 Lev=00 Prnt=00 Port=00 Cnt=00 Dev#=  1 Spd=12  MxCh= 9<br>
D:  Ver= 1.10 Cls=09(hub  ) Sub=00 Prot=00 MxPS=64 #Cfgs=  1<br>
P:  Vendor=1d6b ProdID=0001 Rev=03.11<br>
S:  Manufacturer=Linux 3.11.0-15-generic ohci_hcd<br>
S:  Product=OHCI PCI host controller<br>
S:  SerialNumber=0000:00:02.0<br>
C:  #Ifs= 1 Cfg#= 1 Atr=e0 MxPwr=0mA<br>
I:  If#= 0 Alt= 0 #EPs= 1 Cls=09(hub  ) Sub=00 Prot=00 Driver=hub<br>

T:  Bus=02 Lev=01 Prnt=01 Port=00 Cnt=01 Dev#=  2 Spd=1.5 MxCh= 0<br>
D:  Ver= 1.10 Cls=00(>ifc ) Sub=00 Prot=00 MxPS= 8 #Cfgs=  1<br>
P:  Vendor=04f3 ProdID=0212 Rev=23.24<br>
S:  Product=PS/2+USB Mouse<br>
C:  #Ifs= 1 Cfg#= 1 Atr=a0 MxPwr=100mA<br>
I:  If#= 0 Alt= 0 #EPs= 1 Cls=03(HID  ) Sub=01 Prot=02 Driver=usbhid<br>

T:  Bus=02 Lev=01 Prnt=01 Port=06 Cnt=02 Dev#=  3 Spd=12  MxCh= 0<br>
D:  Ver= 1.10 Cls=00(>ifc ) Sub=00 Prot=00 MxPS= 8 #Cfgs=  1<br>
P:  Vendor=0d8c ProdID=0201 Rev=00.10<br>
S:  Product=PnP Audio Device        <br>
C:  #Ifs= 3 Cfg#= 1 Atr=80 MxPwr=500mA<br>
I:  If#= 0 Alt= 0 #EPs= 1 Cls=01(audio) Sub=01 Prot=00 Driver=snd-usb-audio<br>
I:  If#= 1 Alt= 0 #EPs= 0 Cls=01(audio) Sub=02 Prot=00 Driver=snd-usb-audio<br>
I:  If#= 2 Alt= 0 #EPs= 0 Cls=01(audio) Sub=02 Prot=00 Driver=snd-usb-audio<br>
```

- Then I did the same after attaching it again, and got:

```
usb-devices
```

```
T:  Bus=01 Lev=00 Prnt=00 Port=00 Cnt=00 Dev#=  1 Spd=480 MxCh= 9<br>
D:  Ver= 2.00 Cls=09(hub  ) Sub=00 Prot=00 MxPS=64 #Cfgs=  1<br>
P:  Vendor=1d6b ProdID=0002 Rev=03.11<br>
S:  Manufacturer=Linux 3.11.0-15-generic ehci_hcd<br>
S:  Product=EHCI Host Controller<br>
S:  SerialNumber=0000:00:02.1<br>
C:  #Ifs= 1 Cfg#= 1 Atr=e0 MxPwr=0mA<br>
I:  If#= 0 Alt= 0 #EPs= 1 Cls=09(hub  ) Sub=00 Prot=00 Driver=hub<br>

T:  Bus=01 Lev=01 Prnt=01 Port=01 Cnt=01 Dev#=  5 Spd=480 MxCh= 0<br>
D:  Ver= 2.00 Cls=00(>ifc ) Sub=00 Prot=00 MxPS=64 #Cfgs=  1<br>
P:  Vendor=2020 ProdID=0002 Rev=02.00<br>
S:  Manufacturer=Network Connect<br>
S:  Product=MT6229 <br>
S:  SerialNumber=192101021136100<br>
C:  #Ifs= 1 Cfg#= 1 Atr=80 MxPwr=500mA<br>
I:  If#= 0 Alt= 0 #EPs= 2 Cls=08(stor.) Sub=06 Prot=50 Driver=usb-storage<br>

T:  Bus=02 Lev=00 Prnt=00 Port=00 Cnt=00 Dev#=  1 Spd=12  MxCh= 9<br>
D:  Ver= 1.10 Cls=09(hub  ) Sub=00 Prot=00 MxPS=64 #Cfgs=  1<br>
P:  Vendor=1d6b ProdID=0001 Rev=03.11<br>
S:  Manufacturer=Linux 3.11.0-15-generic ohci_hcd<br>
S:  Product=OHCI PCI host controller<br>
S:  SerialNumber=0000:00:02.0<br>
C:  #Ifs= 1 Cfg#= 1 Atr=e0 MxPwr=0mA<br>
I:  If#= 0 Alt= 0 #EPs= 1 Cls=09(hub  ) Sub=00 Prot=00 Driver=hub<br>

T:  Bus=02 Lev=01 Prnt=01 Port=00 Cnt=01 Dev#=  2 Spd=1.5 MxCh= 0<br>
D:  Ver= 1.10 Cls=00(>ifc ) Sub=00 Prot=00 MxPS= 8 #Cfgs=  1<br>
P:  Vendor=04f3 ProdID=0212 Rev=23.24<br>
S:  Product=PS/2+USB Mouse<br>
C:  #Ifs= 1 Cfg#= 1 Atr=a0 MxPwr=100mA<br>
I:  If#= 0 Alt= 0 #EPs= 1 Cls=03(HID  ) Sub=01 Prot=02 Driver=usbhid<br>

T:  Bus=02 Lev=01 Prnt=01 Port=06 Cnt=02 Dev#=  3 Spd=12  MxCh= 0<br>
D:  Ver= 1.10 Cls=00(>ifc ) Sub=00 Prot=00 MxPS= 8 #Cfgs=  1<br>
P:  Vendor=0d8c ProdID=0201 Rev=00.10<br>
S:  Product=PnP Audio Device        <br>
C:  #Ifs= 3 Cfg#= 1 Atr=80 MxPwr=500mA<br>
I:  If#= 0 Alt= 0 #EPs= 1 Cls=01(audio) Sub=01 Prot=00 Driver=snd-usb-audio<br>
I:  If#= 1 Alt= 0 #EPs= 0 Cls=01(audio) Sub=02 Prot=00 Driver=snd-usb-audio<br>
I:  If#= 2 Alt= 0 #EPs= 0 Cls=01(audio) Sub=02 Prot=00 Driver=snd-usb-audio<br>
```

- Then I did:

```
sudo mount /dev/sr1 /cdrom/
```

got the output as:

```
mount: block device /dev/sr1 is write-protected, mounting read-only
```

- Finally doing:

```
nautilus /cdrom/
```

I got no .tar.bz2 or .deb so that I could make it or directly install its driver.

- In my gesture my device is (lsusb):

> Bus 001 Device 004: ID 2020:0002

and (usb-devices),

```
T:  Bus=01 Lev=01 Prnt=01 Port=01 Cnt=01 Dev#=  5 Spd=480 MxCh= 0<br>
D:  Ver= 2.00 Cls=00(>ifc ) Sub=00 Prot=00 MxPS=64 #Cfgs=  1<br>
P:  Vendor=2020 ProdID=0002 Rev=02.00<br>
S:  Manufacturer=Network Connect<br>
S:  Product=MT6229 <br>
S:  SerialNumber=192101021136100<br>
C:  #Ifs= 1 Cfg#= 1 Atr=80 MxPwr=500mA<br>
I:  If#= 0 Alt= 0 #EPs= 2 Cls=08(stor.) Sub=06 Prot=50 Driver=usb-storage<br>
```

Modem Detail:
beetel
S/N: 110100371109632
IMEI: 911210201163014
Made in China

---

Ubuntu 13.10 (saucy)
GNOME 3.8.4 (Ubuntu 2013-12-05)
Kernel 3.11.0-15-generic (#25-Ubuntu SMP Thu Jan 30 17:22:01 UTC 2014)

OS Type Linux
GCC Version 4.8 (x86_64-linux-gnu)
Xorg Version 1.14.5 (17 December 2013  10:06:15AM)

More strangely this dongle does not show up my 2GB micro SD memory card.

Any help will be saviour for me.
Otherwise I would have to stick to Windows 7,
since without an internet connection ubuntu cannot even be upgraded.

-------------------------------------------------------------------
With the dongle attached I started booting ubuntu, did the following and got:

```
appuraja@appuraja-System-Product-Name:~$ dmesg | tail  <br>
[   24.919630] IPv6: ADDRCONF(NETDEV_UP): eth0: link is not ready<br>
[   26.631204] init: udev-fallback-graphics main process (1237) terminated with status 1<br>
[   26.839371] nvidia 0000:05:00.0: irq 44 for MSI/MSI-X<br>
[   27.340359] vboxdrv: Found 2 processor cores.<br>
[   27.342598] vboxdrv: fAsync=1 offMin=0x5c90e offMax=0x5c90e<br>
[   27.346034] vboxdrv: TSC mode is 'asynchronous', kernel timer mode is 'normal'.<br>
[   27.346040] vboxdrv: Successfully loaded version 4.2.16_Ubuntu (interface 0x001a0005).<br>
[   27.388335] vboxpci: IOMMU not found (not registered)<br>
[   45.088400] FAT-fs (sdb1): Volume was not properly unmounted. Some data may be corrupt. Please run fsck.<br>
[   70.090509] systemd-hostnamed[2508]: Warning: nss-myhostname is not installed. Changing the local hostname might make it unresolveable. Please install nss-myhostname!<br>

appuraja@appuraja-System-Product-Name:~$ lsusb <br>
Bus 001 Device 004: ID 2020:2000  <br>
Bus 001 Device 003: ID 0781:556b SanDisk Corp. <br>
Bus 001 Device 001: ID 1d6b:0002 Linux Foundation 2.0 root hub<br>
Bus 002 Device 003: ID 0d8c:0201 C-Media Electronics, Inc. CM6501<br>
Bus 002 Device 002: ID 04f3:0212 Elan Microelectronics Corp. Laser Mouse<br>
Bus 002 Device 001: ID 1d6b:0001 Linux Foundation 1.1 root hub<br>
<br>
```

Then after removing the dongle I did this and got:

```
appuraja@appuraja-System-Product-Name:~$ dmesg | tail  <br>
[  207.048903] usb 1-4: New USB device strings: Mfr=2, Product=3, SerialNumber=4<br>
[  207.048909] usb 1-4: Product: MT6229 <br>
[  207.048914] usb 1-4: Manufacturer: Network Connect<br>
[  207.048919] usb 1-4: SerialNumber: 192101021136100<br>
[  207.049560] usb-storage 1-4:1.0: USB Mass Storage device detected<br>
[  207.051143] scsi8 : usb-storage 1-4:1.0<br>
[  208.049695] scsi 8:0:0:0: CD-ROM            UsbModem Storage Disk     6229 PQ: 0 ANSI: 0 CCS<br>
[  208.051794] sr1: scsi3-mmc drive: 0x/0x caddy<br>
[  208.053540] sr 8:0:0:0: Attached scsi CD-ROM sr1<br>
[  208.060184] sr 8:0:0:0: Attached scsi generic sg4 type 5<br>

appuraja@appuraja-System-Product-Name:~$ lsusb <br>
Bus 001 Device 006: ID 2020:0002  <br>
Bus 001 Device 003: ID 0781:556b SanDisk Corp. <br>
Bus 001 Device 001: ID 1d6b:0002 Linux Foundation 2.0 root hub<br>
Bus 002 Device 003: ID 0d8c:0201 C-Media Electronics, Inc. CM6501<br>
Bus 002 Device 002: ID 04f3:0212 Elan Microelectronics Corp. Laser Mouse<br>
Bus 002 Device 001: ID 1d6b:0001 Linux Foundation 1.1 root hub<br>
<br>
```

Oh! I forgot to tell you this time I had left a SanDisk Cruzer Edge 8GB pendrive in one USB port.

*Edit* (05/02/2014 12:30 PM):

```
appuraja@appuraja-System-Product-Name:~$ dmesg | tail & lsusb <br/>

[1] 21063<br/>
[ 1519.068041] usb 1-2: new high-speed USB device number 5 using ehci-pci<br/>
[ 1519.200920] usb 1-2: New USB device found, idVendor=2020, idProduct=0002<br/>
[ 1519.200933] usb 1-2: New USB device strings: Mfr=2, Product=3,     SerialNumber=4<br/>
[ 1519.200939] usb 1-2: Product: MT6229 <br/>
[ 1519.200945] usb 1-2: Manufacturer: Network Connect<br/>
[ 1519.200950] usb 1-2: SerialNumber: 192101021136100<br/>
[ 1519.201451] usbserial_generic 1-2:1.0: The "generic" usb-serial driver is only     for testing and one-off prototypes.<br/>
[ 1519.201458] usbserial_generic 1-2:1.0: Tell linux-usb@vger.kernel.org to add     your device to a proper driver.<br/>
[ 1519.201464] usbserial_generic 1-2:1.0: generic converter detected<br/>
[ 1519.203272] usb 1-2: generic converter now attached to ttyUSB0<br/>
Bus 001 Device 005: ID 2020:0002  <br/>
Bus 001 Device 001: ID 1d6b:0002 Linux Foundation 2.0 root hub<br/>
Bus 002 Device 003: ID 0d8c:0201 C-Media Electronics, Inc. CM6501<br/>
Bus 002 Device 002: ID 04f3:0212 Elan Microelectronics Corp. Laser Mouse<br/>
Bus 002 Device 001: ID 1d6b:0001 Linux Foundation 1.1 root hub<br/>
[1]+  Done                    dmesg | tail  <br/>
appuraja@appuraja-System-Product-Name:~$ <br/>
```

*Edit:*

07/02/2014 04:56 P.M.

The issue is finally solved, I followed the complete instruction by Azker Mohamed, and the issue was already 99% solved, I give him many thanks, but for him, thanks would be insufficient appreciation, he helped me a lot.

By the grace of GOD, I suddenly discovered the following and issue is 100% solved:

1) Put the dongle plugged in,

2) Start the computer with ubuntu, it searches for the devices attached, although
you will not see the internal process.

3) Never Ever put a blank modem into any USB port, be equipped with a valid SIM card and
a freshly formatted (you can use Windows 7 also to format)
micro sd memory card. Be sure you have sufficient Internet balance,
at least 10 MB, I recommend 30 MB, which will be useful when we will be testing the connection.
Put both of them into the respective slots.
If your micro sd memory card is shown in the unity launcher, the problem is almost solved.

4) All the problem arises when your micro sd memory card is not shown in the unity launcher,
so manage to show it, here is the process:
Open Terminal by  Ctrl+Meta+T  then type

```
sudo mount /dev/sr
```

then hit 'Tab key' twice at least. If you see the options like   sr0 sr1  then your
card is detected but not mounted, you have to do it manually.
    /dev/sr0 is generally DVD-RW Drive in my case, and   /dev/sr1   is the required micro sd that all we need.
Don't close the terminal and do:
sudo mount /dev/sr1
If ubuntu says ' mount: can't find /dev/sr1 in /etc/fstab or /etc/mtab  ', don't get anxiety, its normal.
DO:

```
sudo eject /dev/sr1
```

Your micro sd is immediately shown in the unity launcher, see it.

5) Now in the same terminal do:

```
sudo modprobe usbserial vendor=0x2020 product=0x0002
```

close the terminal.

6) Start sakish3g and choose the following option one by one:
  a) More Option -> Only switch modem (if applicable). See whether it only says 'Modem Switched',
    if it says 'modem switched to 2020:0002' then there is surely some problem.
  b) Only setup modem (Switch+load module+setup tty), if it says 'Modem setup residing on /dev/ttyUSB0.'
     Then you have one more level of success. If it gives some warning message,
     don't bother even. Its natural. It may ask you for your login password, submit it.

c) Only prepare modem (Setup+PIN unlock+Register Network+Update HAL),
    if it says 'Modem on /dev/ttyUSB0 is registered to Unknown operator 40491.'
    don't bother if any warning is shown.

d) At the top-right corner of your screen (between Ubuntu Cloud and the sound icon)
      network manager applet is present, click to select 'Enable Mobile Broadband',
      already you may see the name of your network provider.
      Wait for a few minute, let the blinking radar sign stop,
      then click the network provider's name e.g., Airtel, BSNL, AIRCEL etc.

e) Open Mozilla Firefox, Opera, Google Chrome, Chrome Browser etc., or open Software 
Updater to check whether there are any updates available.

The Process is complete, but remember a few things:

1) You need the following programs:
lsusb, usb_modeswitch, wvdial and data files for usb_modeswitch.

2) For the first time you need a freshly formatted micro sd maybe formatted with Win7/XP, Linux etc.

3) You need a Valid connection (SIM card) with sufficient balance.

4) If you plan to use the usb-modem with ubuntu even after a few hour later, it doesn't matter,

you may not use it if you don't need it but plug it before booting,
then unplug after boot up and setting it up.
And again plug it when needed. Device is already set up in memory.
Ubuntu searches for attached the devices at boot time so plug the device earlier the boot,
if this not the case and you have just inserted the device while ubuntiu is running,
you may need to re-boot the pc.

5) If you eject the micro sd card after setting up, your modem is still usable if you re-plug it,
but you may need to do the following to access the micro sd drive in it:

```
sudo mount /dev/sr1  
sudo eject /dev/sr1
```

Enjoy the internet.

Comment: May I indeed first ask for an output of `dmesg | tail` (do this by removing and re-plugging back after few seconds) & also following with `lsusb`..

Comment: I edited my post, plese help me....

Comment: That's great to hear! I'm glad it helped you. But this is you who managed to get it fixed. I suggest you to add it as another answer & accept it, in which way you'll earn some points. Anyhow, since you requested I'll edit my post and add it at the end crediting you. :)

Comment: Thanks a lot. Please also mention sakis3g is a wonderful creation in your edit. Whatever problem on can have, it helps. I have no success with GNOME-PPP and Prepaid Manager, they simply not works, sakis3g is however is the ultimate solution. Thank You again for 100 times.

Comment: My answer is too long to put up your edit.. for some reason the existing edits loose its format... I would suggest you to add it as another answer by removing it from your question. Then it will be visible as others will be benefited. :_

Comment: Please mention to mount/eject the micro sd drive (and observe it in unity launcher), in your post, and say the asker has finally chosen your (Mr. Azker Mohamed's) answer as the final solution. If needed mention to read the complete post, finally say the issue is solved and the question is closed. Many Many Thanks to You..

Answer (score 3, accepted):

That's quiet a lot of information that you've specified above. But by looking at the `lsusb` results you **USB Modem** is detecting into the system but not mounting or may be I'm wrong.

Further, by looking at the `lsusb` & `usb-devices` output showed me that your device is listing under;

```
Bus 001 Device 006: ID 2020:0002
```

Please try below specified methods **(Do not try all methods at once. If one didn't work, then try the other)**;

---

## Method 1 (installing usb-modeswitch & modeswitch-data)

- Disconnect/Unplug your modem device from the computer
- If you're able to access internet via LAN or WiFi, then install current version of `usb-modeswitch` and `usb-modeswitch-data` from the **Ubuntu Software Center**. If software center does not list, then try using **Synaptic Package Manager**. You may refer [**Ubuntu Synaptic How-To**](https://help.ubuntu.com/community/SynapticHowto) for the installation as synaptic will not be installed default from Ubuntu 11.10 or later. Below image shows that I've already installed.

[image]

- Else where access internet from another PC, then refer **[USB_ModeSwitch - Handling Mode-Switching USB Devices on Linux](http://f.com)** for options & installation instructions.
- Latest usb-modeswitch-data contains mode-switching option for `2020:0002`. Try connecting your device to see whether you're able to see under the **network manager** applet (make sure you enabled mobile broadband under the nm-applet). You may something similar to below;

[image: nm-applet]

[image: new mbb connection wizard]

- If it did not work, try restarting by removing the device. Plugin it back once logged into the system. If still Ubuntu didn't pick the device, go to the next step.

---

## Method 2 (in-addition to method 1)

#### You may skip obtaining Vendor ID & Product ID if you already know/have it. And also, simply ignore the comments followed by <kbd>#</kbd> while executing commands.

- Open-up a terminal by pressing <kbd>CTRL</kbd>+<kbd>ALT</kbd>+<kbd>T</kbd> & type one of the below (to obtain your **idVendor** & **idProduct** of the device) ;

```
lsusb -v | less                 # keep on hitting enter until you find the device
usb-devices                     # else use this
```

This will show the list of devices attached to the system. And one of the above will display a result like below; (as an example, I've used `lsusb -v | less`).

[image: lsusb output]

In this example; `dVendor is 0x19d2` and `idProduct is 0×0151`

- Open-up a new terminal & type below;

```
sudo rmmod usbserial                 # removes the usbserial if it exists
```

- And then modprobe your USB modem with the acquired ID's (Make sure both the vendor & product ID's are correct)

```
sudo modprobe usbserial vendor=0x19d2 product=0×0151
```

- back-up the file before editing before doing any changes

```
sudo cp /etc/modules /etc/modules.bak         # making a back of the module file
```

- Once back-up is done. Use below command to append it to the module file (once again make sure the ID's are correct). **Altered with appending command**

```
sudo echo “usbserial vendor=0x19d2 product=0×0151″ >> /etc/modules
```

- You're almost done. Reboot the pc to check whether the USB modem is detecting & if not you may follow an additional step using **sakis3g**

---

#### Installing & configuring HSPA modem using sakis3g

- Open a terminal & download `sakis3g` to the PC (internet connection required)

```
wget http://darknet.co.za/wiki/uploads/Posts/sakis3g.tar.gz
```

- Extract the downloaded file & change yourself to root

```
tar -xvzf sakis3g.tar.gz           # to extract the file
sudo su                            # change to root (enter the password when it prompts)
```

[image]

- Copy the extracted file to `/usr/local/bin/`

```
cp sakis3g /usr/local/bin/                # copies the file
```

- Allow the file to be executed by any user within the pc

```
chmod +x /usr/local/bin/sakis3g                # adding executing permission
```

- Once done, open a new terminal with user privilege & type;

```
sakis3g                # this will open sakis 3g software
```

- Select **Connect with 3G -> USB device -> Your Dongle** as below;

[image]

- You may choose your APN if it is listed else select Custom APN and enter your APN. If you're not too unsure about APN, username & password (if any involved) then you may have to contact your ISP to obtain. Complete the steps accordingly & reboot your PC to check whether its working.

[image]

P.S.: I've merged two different posts to give you a better answer. There are other ways to modeprobe your USB modem but I've mentioned very simple & an easy way setting up a connection. If you're still finding difficulties, I may suggest you to refer the sources below.

**Source:** [**Prolink PHS300 Dongle on Ubuntu :: GeekLK**](http://www.geeklk.com/2013/02/prolink-phs300-dongle-on-ubuntu/) & [**How to connect Beetel BG64 HSPA 3G modem on Ubuntu 12.04**](http://ubuntuforums.org/showthread.php?t=2184556)

Comment: I am very much thankful to you because you have invested a lot of time for me to solve my problem.I will test this method tomorrow and inform you accordingly. I can't test it today, my data usage plan (Airtel 25Rs. for 7 days 150MB) will end today. Tomorrow I will recharge it and test it. Thank you so much, really.

Comment: Actually I can't connect my box from the ubuntu partition, but using synaptic package manager I can generate a script (.sh) then on my Win 7 partition using Firefox (with Down-Them-All plugin) I can download the files. No problem. But ubuntu cannot be upgraded, thats the main and ultimate problem.

Comment: Please refer my methods & update me. I may try to assist you further depending on your reply. :)

Comment: Actually my plan end tonight at 12:00, its now 11:01 PM, if due to any reason I fail to update you please keep my request, answer me tomorrow after I update you. Please..

Comment: I tried to experiment with the second method, and looked at the /etc/modules and got no information about the modem, if I need to add some line manually to this file by, $ sudo gedit /etc/modules then please suggest me..

Comment: Echo will not add anything on to the modules. BTW, have you also tried **Installing & configuring HSPA modem using sakis3g**. You may also refer the 2nd link I've provided on the source & refer from **step 3**. (:

Comment: Please tell me what stuff to add to this /etc/modules file, so that I can add something manually and it detects my modem.

Comment: Your modem should detect first, then you may try adding manually later on to `/etc/modules`. But it will not be necessary. I would first suggest you to go through **Method 2** again thoroughly until the end as exactly mentioned. If no luck, you may refer the source link for adding manual entries. I've also altered adding the file to the module on method 2. read it once again. :)

Comment: I also tried to use the sakis3g program but this tells me failed to connect, I will update you this afternoon after tryng the second method again. I am aslo trying to compile embedded modeswitch, but this tells me that no usb.h is found on my system. I guess all the problems are coming as parts of ubuntu saucy, this is an incomplete and buggy version of ubuntu.

Comment: Usually on each and every update, support for modems & USB were enhanced I assume but not for few. Therefore you may have to it manually. I've altered setting on adding lines to `/etc/modules`.. Add it very carefully by having a back-up of the file. :)

Comment: The last thing I'm going to do is to add the following line to this /etc/modules file: usbserial vendor=0x2020 product=0×0002 I still don't know whether luck will favour me or not..

Comment: If I'm not mistaken it should be `sudo echo “usbserial vendor=0x2020 product=0×0002″ >> /etc/modules` & make sure you back-up before proceeding. Good luck!

Comment: Ok I have already added the line usbserial vendor=0x2020 product=0×0002 to this /etc/modules and re-booted my machine tried to do sudo modprobe usbserial vendor=0x2020 product=0×0002 then, sudo echo “usbserial vendor=0x19d2 product=0×0151″ /etc/modules its echoing my device twice. Then again I did sudo modprobe usbserial vendor=0x2020 product=0×0002, then using sakish3g I had chosen Only switch modem (if applicable), then it sayed Modem Switched to 2020:0002. What I need to do further, please tell me..

Comment: Try re-plugging you device and look for `dmesg | tail` & `lsusb` whether it detects. Also from the network manager applet. If not you may have to follow [**this**](http://ubuntuforums.org/showthread.php?t=2184556) which has helped on user to get it fixed.

Comment: I re-plugged the modem did the following, (please see the edits), and got the answer from terminal. What to do now? Please..

Comment: Oh! I did not tell you that I already created a file 2020:0002 and copied this file to  /etc/usb_modeswitch.d folder. And added the line # Beetel 3G HSPA USB Modem - BG64 (made by MediaTek MT6229)
ATTRS{idVendor}=="2020", ATTRS{idProduct}=="0002", RUN+="usb_modeswitch '%b/%k'" to /lib/udev/rules.d/40-usb_modeswitch.rules by commenting the earlier ATTRS{idVendor}=="2020" setting. Changed permission for both the files modules and 40-usb_modeswitch.rules.

Comment: did it helped you to fix the issue??

Comment: Now I will shift the SIM card from my Samsung Champ 3303 to Beetel (ZTE) modem. Actually I had one connectivity the SIM. Frm my Win7 partition I connected my machine via Bluetooth DUN with the help of my mobile. Let me do the rest after inserting the SIM into the modem. I will inform you. Thank you.

Comment: Sorry no hope! I restarted several times, all the time sakis3g says 'Failed to setup modem', 'Failed to prepare modem'. 'Failed to connect', but it can only do 'Switched to Modem 2020:0002'. But nothing helps.. Sorry.. Is there any other way get it worked? Otherwise I will be using it on Win7 either, or sell it in Quicker.com.

Comment: Did you also make sure that the use-modeswitch & modeswitch-data was installed onto the computer. This is the standard steps that I've posted and for most of the users installing these worked even without mode probing. You may have to contact the modem manufacturer for respective drivers at worst case scenario

Comment: I checked usb-modeswitch and modeswitch-data from synaptic, I checked usb_modeswitch from the terminal also, its present. Sure, no doubt! However in your screenshot Mobile Brodband option was present but in my case only 'Enable Networking' is present, this 'Enable Mobile Broadband' is not present, I managed to get a BSNL DSL LAN connection from my naighbour, this connection via LAN is working, but the dongle is not. How can I Enable 'Mobile Broadband' Option? I guess if I can enable it, it would save me a lot.

Comment: It would only be presented when you dongle is detected. If I'm not mistaken this has to with the drivers for sure. If this Ubuntu is a fresh install, I would suggest you to re-install it & give it another try by only updating system at first with `sudo apt-get update`

Comment: More interesting, network-manager is not present in synaptic.

Comment: I installed network-manager-openvpn
network-manager-vpnc
network-manager-openconnectand network-manager-openvpn-gnome
network-manager-vpnc-gnome
network-manager-openconnect-gnome  but no hope!

Comment: I am facing the same problem with a fresh ubuntu install within VMBox. I think Beetel is not supported in ubuntu.

Comment: Thank You Very Very Much.
Finally I managed to get my modem worked after 'following your tutorial first' + 'a minor tweaking'.
Please read the updated post and add it to your answer part,
because I don't want to see anybody is facing the same problem like me, when the issue is already fixed.
One again thank you, I never see a person like you with this huge knowledge helping others these days.
May you prosper in your life.