# 3G Modem visible only on fresh start

Tags: usb-modem, modem, 3g, mint

I'm experiencing very weird behaviour with my 3G modem (USB).

It works only if I will plug it when my computer is turned off and then turn it on. If I do so, the modem works perfectly fine.

When I attach my modem while computer is already working or wake the computer from hibernation/suspension, the modem is not working. How can I get it to work in these situations? Is there a way to force it being discovered by the system?

I use Linux Mint 16, but had the same problem on Ubuntu 13.04. The modem is Huawei E173, `lsusb` gives:

```
Bus 003 Device 004: ID 12d1:1436 Huawei Technologies Co., Ltd. E173 3G Modem (modem-mode)
```

Answer (score 0):

You have to mount/eject the sd card present in it. You have to plug the device before booting, this is required by usb_modeswitch. Here is the solution     [Setting-up Beetel BG64 3G USB modem in ubuntu 13.10 [How-To]](https://askubuntu.com/questions/414963/setting-up-beetel-bg64-3g-usb-modem-in-ubuntu-13-10-how-to)