# 3G modem detected as mass media

Tags: usb, 3g

I have a 3G modem with vendor code `1c9e` and product is `6061` Omega 3.75 G. Since KUbuntu LTS 12.04 it has been detected as mass media. Updating to 12.04.3 did not solve the issue.

Comment: most 3G usb keys have some memory so when you plug it on Windows, it will install the driver. it has always been a problem on Linux.

Answer (score 0):

Try this solution

```
sudo -H gedit /etc/modules
```

At the bottom of the file, make two new lines, like this:

```
usbserial 
option
```

Reboot

There's also a relevant option named `usb-mode-switch`.
You can find more info about it [here on our site](https://askubuntu.com/questions/414963/setting-up-beetel-bg64-3g-usb-modem-in-ubuntu-13-10-how-to)