# Can't Connect to Mobile Broadband 14.04 LTS

Tags: networking, 14.04, mobile-broadband

When I plug the modem I have a mobile broadband option in network menu bar, and I add new mobile broadband connection, and everything is fine. but, when I try to connect it, suddenly the Mobile broadband option in network menu bar dissapear . . so I have to unplug it and plug it again in my laptop to display the mobile broadband option. . . I connect it again, and dissapear again. . . how can I connect to my mobile broadband??

I'm using aego modem. under Ubuntu 14.04 LTS Operating system

Comment: Did you try connecting from command line?

Comment: No, I didn't. I don't know the command

Comment: Ok. I will post it as answer. Try it. I wont guarantee that it will work, though.

Comment: I'm not too sure it would help but its worth having a look through on [**this topic**](http://askubuntu.com/a/416200/179042).

Comment: I've similar problem and solution : 1. Open terminal and run `sudo stop modemmanager`. 2.Plugin modem and wait for 20 seconds. 3. Run `sudo start modemmanager`. Now, Within 20 second, new/existing connection appears in notification area. And you are able to connect (permanently/not-disapperead)!

Comment: This four year old question with no up-voted answers just got bumped to the home page. I see you signed on a fortnight ago though. Have you found a solution yet? If so can you post an answer. Has the problem gone away on it's own? If so can you delete the question? Thanks.

Comment: @WinEunuuchs2Unix i can't delete it 'You cannot delete this question as others have invested time and effort into answering it. For more information, visit the help center.'

Comment: Sorry thought it could be deleted if no upvoted answers. Has the problem gone away on it's own? If so we can close the question and it will stop reappearing on the main page.

Comment: @WinEunuuchs2Unix the solution is buying a new modem, that is the only solution that work for me, you can close this question, thanks.

Answer (score 1):

You may try connecting from the command line. First create a new mobile broadband connection. To do so:-

- Connect your modem. Then select 'New Mobile Broadband connection...' from the panel(aka menu bar) as shown below.

[image]

- Then in the following window press continue.
- Then select your country.
- In the subsequent window select your ISP.
- Then press 'Continue' and then 'Apply'.

Now open the terminal with <kbd>Ctrl</kbd>+<kbd>Alt</kbd>+<kbd>t</kbd> . Then type the following command :-

```
nmcli connection
```

An output similar(not exactly) to the one below will be shown :-

```
NAME                      UUID                                   TYPE              TIMESTAMP-REAL                    
Wired connection 1        ef7249c9-13bf-4d4c-9d5e-14c79371be9e   802-3-ethernet    Monday 21 April 2014 11:23:20 AM IST
BSNL/CellOne New GPRS/3G  a1f89d7a-12d0-4ef8-b76d-cb6e31b11697   gsm               Monday 21 April 2014 03:22:39 PM IST
```

As you can see the output displays all the connections that you have created. Now in the above case if I have to connect with 'BSNL/CellOne New GPRS/3G' then I will type the following command:-

```
nmcli connection up uuid a1f89d7a-12d0-4ef8-b76d-cb6e31b11697
```

As you can see I have typed the UUID of the connection that I want to connect to. So according to your connection you have got to give the UUID in the above command.

Comment: Thanks venki.  but. . . still not working. . . maybe I have to change my modem.

Comment: @UjangKarnadi Sorry I couldn't help. But don't go for a new modem so quickly. Be patient and wait for more answers. Then go for a new one..

Comment: It's OK. . . The good think is I can know more about command line. .

Comment: yesterday I bought huawei modem, and try it with ubuntu, and it work. . . I think my problem is with my modem that doesn't support for ubuntu. .