# Can not connect Qubee Shuttle (UH235) Wimax USB Modem in Ubuntu14.04

Tags: networking, drivers, software-recommendation, usb-modem

I am using `Qubee Shuttle (UH235) Wimax USB Modem` with windows 8.1 which works fine. But when I try to connect it with ubuntu, it can not recognize the modem. I talk with my friends from university, they have this same problem too. They want to use ubuntu but those who are using this modem can not connect to internet in ubuntu. If someone please can give a solution how to use this modem in ubuntu it would be a great help for me. Hear some [specification](http://www.ryanscomputers.com/Qubee-Shuttl-720) of the modem. I am also including some information regarding the modem which I got from windows 8.1

[image]
[image]
[image]
[image]

Comment: There's a thread I see [**launchpad**](https://answers.launchpad.net/ubuntu/+source/gnome-nettool/+question/139831) for the same exact type of the modem. Also, it says that the modules are supporting only up to Ubuntu 9.04.

Comment: Thank you very much, is there any way to make it work with ubuntu 14.04

Comment: I'm not too sure whether this will work, but just have a look on [**Setting-up Beetel BG64 3G USB modem in ubuntu 13.10**](http://askubuntu.com/questions/414963/setting-up-beetel-bg64-3g-usb-modem-in-ubuntu-13-10-how-to). Read the instruction carefully and try it out, also the basics that the OP tried. May be you'll have a luck!