# How to make my Ubuntu 14.04 recognise MMX377G USB Manager for enabling net facility via Modem

Tags: internet, modem-manager

### Output from WINE[image: Output from wine]

### My vendor id etc details

[image: My vendor id etc details]

Note: Using WINE is also of no use since it is giving error. Can you suggest any solution for this which may be worked out from Windows in where the network is working well?

Comment: Modem manager is undetectable whereas I'm using unity interface in ubuntu14.04

Comment: @NoTime yes I used net as its acronym

Comment: Ok so the MMX377G USB Manager is a USB wireless modem correct (3G)? And the software that came with it is specific to Windows?

Comment: Interface was never a problem while the drivers can be. Hi & Welcome to **AU**. Can you elaborate more on what have you done so far? If I can recall, this modem packs with a manual which has installation method for Linux. Isn't it?

Comment: @NoTime I'm not sure that it is specific to Windows only, since in the guide, steps are well provided to use it in ububtu. I followed them well and figured out that vendor id -2020 and product id -0002  after this.. I received message /dev/sr0 in response to command lsusb even when the device is not connected .. How should i proceed further?

Comment: @AzkerM how may i proceed further?

Comment: The modem is not being detected at all..

Comment: Could you please post an output of your errors? Either in the original question, or via a link in the original question (on a site like http://paste.ubuntu.com/)

Comment: http://i.stack.imgur.com/AqWrG.png

Comment: http://i.stack.imgur.com/QNuih.png

Comment: Is it visible in the "Disks" app? Please reply.

Comment: no it isn't -- but the green light in the modem is blinking which according to the manual means working fine.

Comment: Are you dual booting ubuntu?

Comment: @Raphael infact 3 OSs -Windows 8, 7 and Ubuntu

Comment: Then please boot into Windows7 and please tell us if you find any "*.deb" files in the modem drive.

Comment: yes there are both for 32 bit and 64 bit

Comment: I'm not too sure whether this will help! But can you please have look into -> http://askubuntu.com/a/416200/179042 (have a good read on it)

Answer (score 0):

http://code-cocktail.in/micromax-3g-datacard-mmx377g-installation-ubuntu/ seems to be related to if not also the answer to your question.

Comment: this site seems of no use