# Huawei EC315 not working on ubuntu 14.04?

Tags: 14.04, lenovo, usb-modem

Recently I bought a Lenovo B40-70 laptop and I am bugged with tons of problems on Ubuntu 14.04, which worked like charm in my old Dell studio laptop.
The Huawei EC315 provided by Tata Docomo wifi max, a 3g wifi dongle, is not getting recognized in Ubuntu 14.04 either as a mass storage nor as modem.

My system config:

Lenovo B40-70

i3 4005u

Ubuntu 14.04 64 bit

the output of `lsusb`:

```
Bus 001 Device 002: ID 8087:8000 Intel Corp.
Bus 001 Device 001: ID 1d6b:0002 Linux Foundation 2.0 root hub
Bus 003 Device 001: ID 1d6b:0003 Linux Foundation 3.0 root hub
Bus 002 Device 004: ID 138a:0011 Validity Sensors, Inc. VFS5011 Fingerprint Reader
Bus 002 Device 003: ID 0cf3:3004 Atheros Communications, Inc.
Bus 002 Device 002: ID 5986:0652 Acer, Inc 
Bus 002 Device 016: ID 12d1:1f01 Huawei Technologies Co., Ltd. 
Bus 002 Device 001: ID 1d6b:0002 Linux Foundation 2.0 root hub
```

Comment: This may help: http://ubuntuforums.org/showthread.php?t=2236776

Comment: Have a good read and make sure you've those and followed some as per your requirement. http://askubuntu.com/q/414963/179042

Answer (score 0):

To use Tata DoCoMo 3G on Ubuntu OS, find the step below. Read them carefully before you take the step and do not miss the step mentioned herein.

1. You try to connect Tata DoCoMo 3G stick and boot up Ubuntu / system.
2. You may choose network connections and click on the 'New Mobile
   Broadband Connection'
3. Select 'continue' in the dialog box and select "India" as country &
   then click continue.
4. It will show the list of service providers, select 'I don't know my
   provider' option and type 'TATA DOCOMO UMTS', click continue. Note:
   Don't select 'Tata DoCoMo' since it is for Tata Photon+ (2G) and not
   for DoCoMo 3G
5. Now, under billing dialog, select 'My plan is not listed' option and
   enter as "tatadocomo3g" as APN, just click 'confirm' and save your
   settings.

After these steps, you will get Network Connections, you will find "TATA DOCOMO UMTS connection" option and click on it. In case if it does not connect to internet then you can just unplug and then plug your 3G stick.

Hope this helps!

Comment: not working also it is not gsm device it is cdma device here's the link http://www.tataphoton.com/photon-max-wifi.aspx